# Spring Boot app cannot inject / autowire 'javax.enterprise.event.Event'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following a tutorial, where Event is injected like this into the Controller class:

```
  @Inject
  Event<ExportedEvent<?, ?>> event;
```

However, when I run my spring boot application, it fails with the following:

```
***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************


Description:


Field event in com.example.mydemo.controller.MyResource required a 
bean of type 'javax.enterprise.event.Event' that could not be found.


The injection point has the following annotations:

- @javax.inject.Inject()
```

The main Spring Boot Application is in the package "com.example.mydemo", so I guess it scans everything starting from that package. Is it the reason the Event bean is not found?

How can this be fixed? I tried using @ComponentScan and add the package but it did not work.

Thanks you!

Comment: To be able to inject a `java.enterprise.event.Event` instance as a bean, something must have defined such a bean. Where do you expect the `Event` bean to come from?

Comment: Which tutorial? And are you actually using the proper event?

Comment: https://debezium.io/blog/2019/02/19/reliable-microservices-data-exchange-with-the-outbox-pattern/ this is the tutorial and the related github repo: https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/outbox/order-service/src/main/java/io/debezium/examples/outbox/order/service/OrderService.java#L34-L35

Comment: @texmelex Did you solve the problem ? I am facing the same issue